# Phase plot producing an empty output

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, parametric-functions

```
Clear[x1, x2, t];

eqn = {x1'[t] == x1[t] - x1[t].x2[t], x2'[t] == x2[t] + x1[t].x2[t]}

ics = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1};

sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{eqn, ics}], {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}];
ParametricPlot[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x1[t], x2[t]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

How can I plot `x1` against to `x2`? How can I solve and plot this equations?

Comment: This `Plot[{x1[t]+.1,x2[t]/40000}/.sol, {t,0,10},PlotRange->All]` shows that `x2` has a range that is about 40000 times greater than x1. That will likely make `ParametricPlot` appear as a vertical line. Note I also replaced two of your "." with "\*".

Comment: Right, I would suggest plotting $x_1(t)$ vs $x_2(t)$ on a logarithmic scale.  Please see below.

Answer (score 2):

Copying you same Code

```
eqn = {x1'[t] == x1[t] - x1[t]*x2[t], x2'[t] == x2[t] + x1[t]*x2[t]}

ics = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1};

sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{eqn, ics}], {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

This do it this way, the problem is your range is totally big gapped in x1 and x2, so i tried to use t small as possible t between 0 and 1 thats it

```
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1}]
p2 = Plot[Evaluate[{x2[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 1}]
Show[{p1, p2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 5}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For multiplication you have to use space or `*` not `.`.

```
Clear[x1, x2, t];    

eqn = {x1'[t] == x1[t] - x1[t]*x2[t], x2'[t] == x2[t] + x1[t]*x2[t]}

ics = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1};

sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{eqn, ics}], {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Now when you try to phase plot, you getting a vertical line as output, misleading you to think of it as an empty plot. But it is not, this is because of the huge magnitude difference between `x1[t]` and `x2[t]`. Thus you are suppose to tuneup the `PlotRange`,

```
ParametricPlot[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x1[t], x2[t]},
 PlotRange -> {{0,3},{0,10}}]
```

To explore more, let us plot the phase plane for a set of initial conditions,

```
sol[x0_?NumericQ] := First@NDSolve[{x1'[t] == x1[t] - x1[t]*x2[t], 
     x2'[t] == x2[t] + x1[t]*x2[t], x1[0] == x0, x2[0] == x0}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol[#] & /@ Range[-5, 5, 0.3]], {t, 0, 
  10}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 6}, {-6, 20}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: ı am trying but plot is empty

Comment: @merve It’s not empty you just need to adjust the PlotRange

Comment: how can ı adjust plot range can you give me an example please

Comment: thank yo so much

Answer (score 0):

You might find it interesting that there are a lot of hidden details in the plot!  Plotting on a logarithmic scale with `PrecisionGoal->`$\infty$, we obtain a smoother curve (smoother than without setting `PrecisionGoal`).  I've also plotted `Abs[x1[t]]` rather than `x1[t]` so that the curve is continuous.  `Log10[]` will disregard negative values.

```
Clear[x1, x2, t];
eqn = {x1'[t] == x1[t] - x1[t] x2[t], x2'[t] == x2[t] + x1[t] x2[t]};
ics = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{eqn, ics}], {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> \[Infinity]];
ParametricPlot[Log10@{Abs[x1[t]], x2[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, 
FrameLabel -> {"Log10[|x1[t]|]", "Log10[x2[t]]"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle->Blue,
AspectRatio -> 2, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, FrameLabel -> {t, "{x1[t], x2[t]}"},
     PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 2, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
     PlotLegends -> {x1[t], x2[t]}]
```

The discontinuities are where $x_1(t)$ are negative.  This is because `LogPlot[]` will ignore negative values.  We can make the blue curve continuous by plotting $|x_1(t)|$ rather than $x_1(t)$ (or alternatively, we could have added $-x_1(t)$ to the plot).

[image]

When $t > \, \approx 2 $ seconds, the function $|x_1(t)|$ starts to show large fluctuations (on a logarithmic scale).